What does the EMF wave form of a read DC generator with multiple poles, multiple armature conductors, and multiple commutator segments look like
In a simple two pole one coil DC generator, all the commutator segments are in contact with the brushes so they capture the full emf sinusoidal waveform.  In a real DC generator (with multiple poles, multiple armature conductors, and multiple commutator segments) , only few commutator segments are in contact with the brushes.  Could someone please advise how the EMF waveform of a real DC generator looks like?
